# Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в этом случае?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Посмотреть(,) как устроено приложение можно в разделе "о приложении".

Нужна ли в данном случае запятая после "посмотреть"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужна не только эта запятая, но и вторая, закрывающая придаточное:

> *Посмотреть, как устроено приложение, можно в разделе "о приложении".*

Answer (score 0):

Ставится запятая, она связывает части сложноподчиненного предложения.